# MIPS Architecture) write allocation in cache and multiword block

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture

apologies first english is not my first language.

**Multiword Block Considerations
...
Write misses (D$)
Can’t use write tag, one word of data from the new block, and three words allocate or will end up with a “garbled” block in the cache (e.g., for 4 word blocks, a new if data from the old block), so must fetch the block from memory first and pay the stall time**

I am studying computer architecture (the textbook uses MIPS) and the professor said usually write allocate does not even fetch the data from the memory but just writes in cache, is this correct?

As for the multi-word blocks however, write allocate needs to fetch the data from memory first. Am I right? If so, I don't understand this.
I saw a similar question that was asked 5 years ago but it didn't answer my question.
How can it be "gargled"? Any word that needs to be updated is marked with a dirty bit. so if it is 4 word-block and just one of the words needs to be updated, just one will be updated when the block is replaced (write-back) or as soon as the write is done (write-through).

Only one word out of the whole block needs updating, and the system can do so with the tags and all so why do you have to fetch the memory for write-allocate? I would really appreciate a reply I'm very confused. Thank you.

Comment: If you do fetch when you write-allocate, you only need one dirty bit for the whole cache line, instead of one for each byte.  You also don't have any complex merging to do later.

Comment: *Only one word out of the whole block needs updating, and the system can do so with the tags*.  Tags are not dirty-bits within a line.  They're the part of the cache that lets you tell whether the high bits of an address match, to tell if a block is caching the address you want or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm 2 years late... hopefully this will help anyone else that has this issue in the future.

For a single-word block, write allocate can be used on a write miss since it will replace the entire block in the cache. If the dirty bit is set for the data being replaced, it must be written back to memory. Then, the new data is stored, the tag is updated, and the dirty bit is set.

For a multi-word block, a write miss indicates that the word to be stored is not a part of any blocks currently in the cache. Therefore, write allocate has nowhere to place the new word data since it does not know the other data stored in the other, unchanged words of the same block.

For example, for a cache with 4 word blocks, suppose you want to use write allocate. On a write miss, you would choose a block to overwrite and store the new data in the word addressed by the offset and update the tag and dirty bits. However, the data in the other three words is still the data from the overwritten block. Later, when you write back this block, those three words will overwrite any data that was there before but should not have been changed. The only way to properly preserve the data in the three unused words is to fetch the block before writing.